# Can I overwrite Facebook's Like button's comment box position?

Tags: html, css, facebook

I want to put a facebook like button at the bottom of mywebpage, but when someone clicks on that button the pop-up box for writing comments appears underneath it so it cannot be seen because it goes off the page. Can I make that pop-up comment box appear on the top of the Like button? If it is possible, how?

Comment: Generally, you can't/shouldn't manipulate things inside an iframe such as the 'like' widget, but you can manipulate the dimensions/position of the iframe itself.  Perhaps make it bigger when clicked, so all of its content can be seen.

Comment: I believe I'm not the only to face this problem. There must be some way to manipualte it..